# Porque só a primeira modal funciona?

Tags: javascript

Tenho dois formulários, um para inserir e o outro para editar. Esses formulários estão em modals. As modals abrem quando clico no botão "editar", mas a modal de "inserir" não abre e ainda trava a página. Não sei onde estou errando.

Pelos testes que fiz, verifiquei que somente a modal que vem escrita primeiro no código que funciona.

segue o código abaixo:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Olho de Deus - Contratos</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" style="margin-right: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalInsert">Novo contrato</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-right: 20px;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalUpdate">Editar contrato</button>
<!-- MODALS -->
<!-- UPDATE -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalUpdate" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%;">
  <form action="processaContratos.php?operacao=update" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar Contrato</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id_update">
        <h5>Contrato inicial</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="contratada_update" name="contratada" placeholder="Contratada">
          <label for="bloco">Contratada</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="objeto_update" name="objeto" placeholder="Objeto">
          <label for="bloco">Objeto</label><br>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar alterações</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- INSERT -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalInsert" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%;">
  <form action="processaContratos.php?operacao=insert" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adicionar novo Contrato</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
        <h5>Contrato inicial</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="contratada_insert" name="contratada_insert" placeholder="Contratada">
          <label for="bloco">Contratada</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="objeto_insert" name="objeto_insert" placeholder="Objeto">
          <label for="bloco">Objeto</label><br>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar alterações</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas adicione `</div>` antes do comentario insert.

provavelmente isso aconteceu porque a indentação não está muito boa, e aconteceu da div do modal não fechar e "comer" o outro modal junto.

abaixo está o seu código com a indentação correta.

espero ter ajudado Allan

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Olho de Deus - Contratos</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" style="margin-right: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
data-bs-target="#modalInsert">Novo contrato</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-right: 20px;" data-bs-toggle="modal"
data-bs-target="#modalUpdate">Editar contrato</button>
  <!-- MODALS -->
  <!-- UPDATE -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalUpdate" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
style="width: 100%;">
<form action="processaContratos.php?operacao=update" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar Contrato</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id_update">
        <h5>Contrato inicial</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="contratada_update"
            name="contratada" placeholder="Contratada">
          <label for="bloco">Contratada</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="objeto_update"
            name="objeto" placeholder="Objeto">
          <label for="bloco">Objeto</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar alterações</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- INSERT -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalInsert" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
style="width: 100%;">
<form action="processaContratos.php?operacao=insert" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adicionar novo Contrato</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <h5>Contrato inicial</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="contratada_insert"
            name="contratada_insert" placeholder="Contratada">
          <label for="bloco">Contratada</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input type="text" min="1" style="width: 800px;" required class="form-control" id="objeto_insert"
            name="objeto_insert" placeholder="Objeto">
          <label for="bloco">Objeto</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar alterações</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```